# Wordpress page goes blank after form submit

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I'm following a tutorial that creates form with Advanced Custom Fields that updates the user profile. When I press the submit button the page turns blank (white). Maybe you folks can see a line of code below that is causing the trouble. The tutorial says it tells Wordpress that it's updating a user not the page.

I'd like the page to reload, or maybe redirect to another page after it submits.

Tutorial Ref: https://usersinsights.com/acf-user-profile/

This code is in the functions.php. It converts the shortcode and submits the data, which does update, but after it submits the page has nothing on it, it's just blank.

```
    function my_acf_user_form_func( $atts ) {
     
    
      $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'field_group' => ''
      ), $atts );
     
      $uid = get_current_user_id();
      
      if ( ! empty ( $a['field_group'] ) && ! empty ( $uid ) ) {
        $options = array(
          'post_id' => 'user_'.$uid,
          'field_groups' => array( intval( $a['field_group'] ) ),
          'return' => add_query_arg( 'updated', 'true', get_permalink())
        );
        
        ob_start();
        
        acf_form( $options );
        $form = ob_get_contents();
        
        ob_end_clean();
    
      }
      
        return $form;
        
    
    }
     
    add_shortcode( 'my_acf_user_form', 'my_acf_user_form_func' );
    
    //adding AFC form head
    function add_acf_form_head(){
        global $post;
        
      if ( !empty($post) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'my_acf_user_form' ) ) {
            acf_form_head();
        }
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_acf_form_head', 7 );
```

Comment: It's easier for you to enable error checking and error display. you can do this in your wp-config.php file - `define( 'WP_DEBUG',true);`
`define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY',TRUE );` - that will hopefully tell you which line is erroring out

Comment: Thanks John. That lead me on the path to solve it. I found out that it did not like acf_form_head() being added on to the head (wp_head). Then I found an article that said acf_form_head()  should come before get_header(). I added that on the page.php since I couldn't think of a way to do it in functions.php and it worked! :) Thanks the hint that lead to the solution. I will always keep wp_debug_display on when testing.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to John Tyner's tip to turn on wp_debug_display I found the problem had something to do with the code being added to the wp_head. I searched online and found out from an ACF article that acf_form_head() needs to go before the header.

Change:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_acf_form_head', 7 );
```

to

```
add_action( 'get_header', 'add_acf_form_head', 0 );
```

It works! :)

Comment: I had no priority on my action. Added the 0 and it worked great! Thank you!